# Facebook api reactions of a personal page post doesn't work

Tags: facebook

I am using Facebook graph API.
https://graph.facebook.com/post-id/reactions to get reactions.
Post id is `story_fbid` value then _ then id it works if the post is a page post not a personal page post how to solve this problem?

I tried to put just `story_fbid` and didn't work either.